# How do I custom design a select tab?

Tags: html, css, select, drop-down-menu

I have this html and css code:

```css
.select {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <select size=5 id="myList" class="list-content" onchange="setPicture();"></select>
</label>
```

However, I am unable to see any results for any changes I make in css. Can ayone suggest what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: You're using `.select` in the CSS, but `class="list-content"` in the HTML.

Comment: Also I think you should write `appearance:none` instead of `list-style-type:none`, because `select`s don't have list style types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the dot so you have:

```
select {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 text-align: center;
```

}

this is now the styling for all `<select>`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `.select` in your CSS to either `#myList` or `.list-content`.
Let me know if it doesn't help.